# New Mexico Township and Range Shapefile

Tags: shapefile, data, township-range-section

I'm having difficulty locating a shapefile for New Mexico PLSS Townships and Ranges.  Does anyone have recommendations on where to find this data.

Comment: Welcome to GIS Stack Exchange! What sites have you tried so far?

Comment: Have you looked [here](https://rgis-data.unm.edu/rgisportal/)?

Comment: I tried using the BLM website, NM taxation and Revenue website, as well as the ArcGis Database.  I just found a CAD database and downloading it now.  Hoping the shapefile is in there!

Comment: reevesii - any idea how to download the data or is it just an interactive map?

Answer (score 3):

The USDA [Geospatial Data Gateway](https://datagateway.nrcs.usda.gov/) has PLSS township/range shapefiles by state, as well as a ton of other excellent free data.

Comment: Excellent, thank you!  Looks like this should work, downloading it now.

Comment: Great to hear. If that works, don't forget to mark the answer as accepted.

Answer (score 2):

It isn't a shp but you can view it in kml through here http://Earthpoint.us/Townships.aspx